# Function to check if some fields are activated - Odoo v8 to Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

consider this function:

```
@api.multi
def create_invoice(self):
    """ Create a invoice refund
    """

    self.ensure_one()
    wizard_brw = self.browse() 
    inv_id = self._context.get('active_id')
    for wizard in wizard_brw:
        if not wizard.sure:
            raise UserError(
                _("Validation error!"),
                _("Please confirm that you know what you're doing by"
                  " checking the option bellow!"))
        if (wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.jour_id and
                wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.acc_id):
            inv_id = self.action_invoice_create(wizard,
                                                wizard.invoice_id) 
        else:
            raise UserError(
                _('Validation error!'),
                _("You must go to the company form and configure a journal"
                  " and an account for damaged invoices"))
    return self.new_open_window([inv_id], 'action_invoice_tree1', 'account')
```

This button, among other things, should check if the `company_id` has the `jour_id` field selected, or `acc_id`.

These fields on `res.partner` are these:

```
class ResCompany(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.company'

jour_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal', string='Journal', required=False,
    help="Default journal for damaged invoices")
acc_id = fields.Many2one('account.account', string='Account', 
    help="Default account used for invoices and lines from damaged invoices")
printer_fiscal = fields.Boolean(string='Manages fiscal printer',
    help='Indicates that the company can operate a fiscal printer')
```

Right now, this function isn't showing any warning or `UserError`, of course I have imported `from odoo.exceptions import UserError`

So, I guess there is something with the function, btw, this was manually migrated from Odoo v8, it's frm a localization.

The original method looked like this:

```
def create_invoice(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """ Create a invoice refund
    """
    context = context or {}
    wizard_brw = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    inv_id = context.get('active_id')
    for wizard in wizard_brw:
        if not wizard.sure:
            raise osv.except_osv(
                _("Validation error!"),
                _("Please confirm that you know what you're doing by"
                  " checking the option bellow!"))
        if (wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.jour_id and
                wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.acc_id):
            inv_id = self.action_invoice_create(cr, uid, ids, wizard,
                                                wizard.invoice_id, context)
        else:
            raise osv.except_osv(
                _('Validation error!'),
                _("You must go to the company form and configure a journal"
                  " and an account for damaged invoices"))
    return self.new_open_window(cr, uid, ids, [inv_id],
                                'action_invoice_tree1', 'account')
```

I think this function could be far easier (less code) than it is, I just tried to respect the original one.

How can I achieve this on "pure" new API (from Odoo v10 community)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.ensure_one()
wizard_brw = self.browse() 
inv_id = self._context.get('active_id')
for wizard in wizard_brw:
```

this is wrong for 2 reasons:

1. you are using `ensure_one` so there's no need to loop
2. you are looping on an empty recordset (you are not browsing anything)

You should just do:

```
self.ensure_one()
if not self.sure:
     # do stuff
```

`self` is already your wizard ;)